# Pygame won't display the movement of the letter tile when the mouse moves

Tags: python, pygame

I'm coding a scrabble game and when checking the motion of the letters on the board, nothing happens. I successfuly loaded the image on the scrabble board, but command to move the letter when the mouse is clicked and moved is not working.

Here is the first part where the game starts to run.

```
    def rungame(self):
    """Start the main loop of the game."""
    while True:
        self.check_events()
        self.draw_board()
        self.update_screen()
```

And the events that follow:

```
    def check_events(self):
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            a_selected = self.a_rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos)
            if a_selected:
                self.dragging = True
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            self._check_tile_letter_collision()
            self._drop_letter()
            self.dragging = False

        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
            mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            self._move_let(mouse_pos)
```

So far, everything is looking good. But here comes the problem:

```
def _move_let(self, mouse_pos):
    if self.dragging:
        if 219 < mouse_pos[0] < 680 and 118 < mouse_pos[1] < 580:
            self.a_rect.x = mouse_pos[0]
            self.a_rect.y = mouse_pos[1]
            print(self.a_rect.x, self.a_rect.y)
```

So I tried to print the result and see if there is some mistakes but the print call works fine and I see the x and y values that are attributed to the image from the mouse, but the image is not moving.
I made sure I called the blit and display methods at the end, so that is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, the problem was coming from the order of tve calls in the rungame method.
The board should be drawn first before checking events!